# R - Assign observation into the classes (sturges rule)

Tags: r

I have a list of 70 observations (amounts) that I would like to assign to classes (intervals) and perform some basic calculations (relative frequency, cumulative frequency, etc).

First question is, if there is a function for Sturges rule (i.e returns the number and length of the classes)?

Second question is, if there is a function in R that is similar to Excel's function frequency (based on classes borders counts the observations per class)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Sturges rule is the default split used by the `hist` function and the function that does it is:

```
?nclass.Sturges
```

There are various grouping functions in R. I suspect one of `cut`, `table` or `xtabs` may be what you want. (I didn't understand what was meant by "based on classes borders counts the observations per class".) `cut` gives a vector of the same length, whereas the other two tally the counts, returning a contingency table.